# Add more nodes on a live OCFS2 cluster

Tags: ocfs2

I have a OCFS cluster with 4 nodes at the moment. I would like to add another 6.

What I did:

- I edited the /etc/ocfs2/cluster.conf file and added all the desirable nodes. Then I copied to all the nodes.
- When I tried to mount the partition from Node06, I could see on dmesg of Node01 that an unknown node was trying to access it.
- Then I copied the directories of /sys/kernel/config/cluster/ocfs2/node/Node05-Node10 to the existing Nodes Node01-Node04.
- After that the new nodes could connect but I was exceeding the slots limit which is 4 slots.
- I tried to increase it by running tunefs.ocfs2 -N 10 /dev/sdxX but it returns the error "tunefs.ocfs2: Trylock failed while opening device "/dev/sdxX""

How to increase the slot limit whithout taking the cluster down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly I had to unmount the drive from all the nodes and then run the tunefs.ocfs2 -N 10 /dev/sdxX command. That solve the issue.